# Where do I place JSON data in Expo project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, assets, expo

Does having assets in your app mean your app will rely on internet connection when you build and deploy with expo?

My app is using JSON data, and images, and I don’t want users to need internet connection to use it, but after releasing it doesn’t load up without internet connection and sometimes even crashes.

I am using es6 imports to read the JSON in assets and set Redux state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** from SDK 24 onwards, the answer has changed. You can now bundle some assets within your app binary and do not depend from the CDN anymore.

From [the documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/offline-support.html#bundle-your-assets-inside-your-standalone-binary):

> **Bundle your assets inside your standalone binary**
>   Expo can bundle assets into your standalone binary during the build process so that they will be available immediately, even if the user has never run your app before. This is important if:
>   Your users may not have internet the first time they open your app, or
>   If your app relies on a nontrivial amount of assets for the very first screen to function properly.

See [the announcement with some neat explanations and graphs here](https://blog.expo.io/under-the-hood-offline-assets-in-expo-98614adcf9e5).

**Old accepted answer below:** I decided to change this as it is no longer correct and I was finding my own answer in a google search. This way we avoid people don´t get wrong information.

Yes, currently your users will need an internet connection. As described in the documentation, assets are currently uploaded to a Content Delivery Network (CDN) and not packaged with your app. Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/assets.html):

> **In production**
>   Each time you publish your app, Expo will upload your assets to Amazon CloudFront, a blazing fast CDN. It does this in an intelligent way to ensure your deploys remain fast: if an asset has not changed since your previous deploy, it is skipped. You don’t have to do anything for this to work, it is all automatically handled by Expo.

I hope they change it or make it optional in the future, as I am also interested in apps without internet connection.